# Konva.js - how to get the position of an object that is in a group

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

How to get a current postion of an object that is in group, when the group is dragged. I can only get a position of the group itself, but I need positions of members of the group dynamically.

Example: this gives me the X position of the mynode, but only when mynode is ungrouped. If I group it, then it is not updated when the group is dragged.

`layer.findOne('#'+mynode).x()`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is using absolutePosition() method to get the absolute position of a node.